# How do I set the width and height of a textarea using CSS?

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc

Here is my css:

```
.editor-field textarea {
    width : 400;
    height : 100px;
}
```

Here is the markup from my view:

```
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Visit.BehavioralObservations)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Visit.BehavioralObservations)
        </div>
```

And here is the annotation of my model showing the MultilineText attribute:

```
    [DisplayName("Behavioral Observations")]
    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    public string BehavioralObservations { get; set; }
```

Why can't I set the width of this textarea? I can adjust the height in my CSS and it looks correct (verified with Chrome Developer tools) but the width doesn't change. Chrome says the width is an invalid property value and has a strike-through applied to the property along with a yellow triangle displayed adjacent to the property.

FYI, this is not limited to Chrome. IE8 has the same issue.

Thoughts? How do I fix this? Thanks!

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You left off `px`:

```css
.editor-field textarea {
    width : 400px;
    height : 100px;
}
```

Comment: You gotta be kidding... Wow, that's embarrassing :-) Thanks!

Answer (score 57):

try to use `TextAreaFor` helper method and set `cols` and `rows` html property

Sample

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(model=>model.MyMultilineText, new {rows="6", cols="10"})
```

I Hope this help.
Regards.

Comment: Hello, Do you know how to set the resizing property of the textarea to false in the View?

Answer (score 18):

After some time searching for it, the best way is to use one of the **overloads** of the method **TextAreaFor()**

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Visit.BehavioralObservations, 10, 40, new { HtmlAttributes = new { } })
```

The 10 is the number of **rows**, the 40 is the number of **columns**

Answer (score 7):

Code:

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Message, 30, 10, new { @class = "what" })
```

Answer (score 7):

`ASP MVC` default project has `site.css` with 
`max-width:280` for `textarea` -- remove that and try something like this

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.ComicText, new { style = "width: 700px; height:150px;" })
```

Answer (score 2):

style can be specified in the link will

@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.values, new {style = "width: 700px; height:200px;"})